# Locker Service does not support jQuery DataTable plugin

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, locker-service

I am using [DataTable](https://datatables.net/) to display table in Lightning Component. Locker Service is enabled for developer sandbox. When I apply Component version as 40.0, the data table does not generate its UI. Whereas , when I use the version below 40.0 it works without any issues.

Referring to [LockerService and Lightning Container Component: Securely Using Third-Party Libraries in Lightning Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/02/lockerservice-lightning-container-third-party-libraries-lightning-components.html), says that DataTables are supported in Locker Service enabled orgs.

Is any one faced similar kind of issue before?

Comment: What issue are you facing? Did you check browser console to see if there are any issues?

Comment: Hello Devendra, which versions of JQuery and DataTable are you using? I can take a look (also some quick repro steps would help).

Comment: Hi @JF, I am using following versions - jQuery : v1.12.4
DataTables 1.10.9
Responsive 1.0.7. Which are the compatible versions that I need to include ?

Comment: @RedDevil, I am getting folowing error when I apply version 40 for a lightning component - "TypeError: div.attributes[eventName] is undefined throws"

Comment: We've not been able to have jQuery V1 working properly, and we are recommending your use V2 or V3. In particular, I know jQuery v2.2.4 has been very stable for most. Give it a shot, post your results, and we will take it from there!

Comment: @JF Paradis, I have used following files with jQueryv2.2.4 as you have suggested. https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.1.1/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.1.1/js/responsive.bootstrap.min.js. The issues which I am receiving are responsive UI does not work in Salesforce1 mobile app when I kee component version as 40.0. In desktop version pagination does not work at version 40. Those works at version 39.

Comment: @JF If you are aware any data table versions which are compatible with Locker Service, please let me know. I will test with those versions as well. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: We were successful with Datatables 1.10.12, but maybe our tests are incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

> Referring to [LockerService and Lightning Container Component](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/02/lockerservice-lightning-container-third-party-libraries-lightning-components.html):
>   Securely Using Third-Party Libraries in Lightning Components, says
>   that DataTables are supported in Locker Service enabled orgs.

No, it does not say that DataTables is supported, it specificaly mentions that:

> Version 1.10.12

of DataTables is supported. Always check the library versions you are using when referring to this documentation.

If your library is not listed and testing the library in a component using API v40+ doesn't work, then it is most likely not supported.